# rails 3 override model setter

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm making a plugin and I need it to override a setter/getter for my model. Here's the code I have so far:

```
module Iplong
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    module ClassMethods
        ...

        def override_setter
            self.class_eval %(
                def #{attribute}=(raw_value)
                    self[:#{attribute}] = #{ip2long('raw_value')}
                end
            )
        end
    end

end

ActiveRecord::Base.send :include, Iplong
```

Notice the `raw_value` param. If I print it in the evalued code it prints the correct value that comes when the attribute is set but if I print it inside the `ip2long` function where it is sent it returns a string: `raw_value` so how do I pass this parameter without it being interpreted as string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in this particular piece of code:

```
"#{ip2long('raw_value')}"
```

Translating this from a string to Ruby code you'd get:

```
ip2long('raw_value')
```

So you're actually sending the 'raw_value' string instead of the actual value of that variable.

Replace the code with:

```
"#{ip2long(raw_value)}"
```

And you should be fine.

*Edit: This sample code shows how it'd work:*

```
class A
  attr_accessor :ip

  def ip2num(ip)
    ip.gsub(".", "")
  end

  def override(attr)
    code = "def #{attr}=(value); @ip = ip2num(value); end"
  self.class.class_eval(code)
  end
end

a = A.new
a.ip = "0.0.0.0"
puts a.ip

a.override("ip")
a.ip = "0.0.0.0"
puts a.ip
```

Comment: tried that but I get `undefined local variable or method `raw_value' for #<Class:0x00000003bc72a0>`

Comment: Not sure where the prob. might be but I edited the answer to include some sample code that should help you see what I meant.